# Creating a CSV file from multiple lists

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, output

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm struggling to save some variables in a csv file.

I have my output in two lists that I want to put into a csv file. One is a list of integers, the other is a list of floats.

Say my lists are:

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
bar = [5.1, 10.1, 15.1, 20.1, 25.1]
```

I know how to make csv files from lists of integers:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10] ])
numpy.savetxt("dog.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

But I can not simply replace the lists with foo and bar as it returns an error.Mainly because I don't think you can put multiple lists in asarray like this.

How can I create a CSV file with the two lists foo and bar as my two rows?

ANY help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for your replies! After seeing how you wrote the line.

```
a = ...
```

I discovered that I was making a syntax error with inputting the lists into asarray :P

Comment: try to use `numpy.array()` instead of `numpy.asarray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with numpy 1.8:

```
In [32]: foo = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [33]: bar = [5.1, 10.1, 15.1, 20.1, 25.1]

In [34]: a = numpy.asarray([ foo,bar ])

In [35]: a
Out[35]:
array([[  1. ,   2. ,   3. ,   4. ,   5. ],
       [  5.1,  10.1,  15.1,  20.1,  25.1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! My error was in what you've written as In[34]. I made a syntax error when inputting the two lists into the brackets. Brilliant!